# Constraints violations always empty when use Symfony validator component

Tags: symfony, validation

I have encourred a strange problem when use a Symfony validator, the constraints violations is always empty even if entity does not respect constraints.

Entity :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
  /**
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  */
  public $name;
}
```

The code to use validator :

```
$Author = new Author();

$validator = Validation::createValidator();
var_dump( count($validator-> validate($Author)) );
```

Result : 0

Do you have an idea on the origin of this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Jérémy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use the validator pre-configured by Symfony. Is that intended? Usually you validate objects by either injecting the validator into your service or by pulling it from the container (its id is `validator`).

In your case, you are going to create a new validator instance. However, if not enabled explicitly, annotation support is turned off. You would have to enable it yourself (but the approach of using the configured `validator` service as written above is usually what you want to do):

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->getValidator();
```

Comment: As of Symfony 6, we also to have to call `->addDefaultDoctrineAnnotationReader()` explicitly. Before, it was done by the `enableAnnotationMapping()` function.

Answer (score 0):

enabled in the main config file:

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    validation: { enabled: true }
```

enable_annotations:

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

official doc:
[Validation Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration)